# HTML table ends up outside of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a table inside of a div called "board" but it somehow ends up beneath it. The contents of the table are created in Javascript. At the bottom of the post I have a JSFiddle link that I hope will clarify what I mean.

HTML

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testclass.css">
</head>

<script src="testclass.js" defer></script>

<center>
  <div id="board">
    <table id="table">
    </table>
  </div>
</center>
```

CSS

```
.empty {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Javascript

```
let board = document.getElementById("board");
let table = document.getElementById("table");

let element = document.createElement("BUTTON");
element.innerHTML = "TEXT SHOULD BE BELOW THE SQUARE";
board.appendChild(element);

var br = document.createElement("br");
board.appendChild(br);

var info = document.createTextNode("This text should also be below the SQUARE");
board.appendChild(info);

var type = " empty";

var tr = document.createElement("tr");

var td = document.createElement("td");

table.append(tr);

td.className = type;

tr.append(td);

var td2 = document.createElement("tr");

tr.append(td2);
```

MCVE: https://jsfiddle.net/pycuoghw/13/

Comment: It's because your table has a position of absolute, which removes it from the normal flow of the document.

Comment: @MichaelvE Yes, that was it! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

A solution might be to put the position absolute in the center tag:

```js
let board = document.getElementById("board");
let table = document.getElementById("table");

let element = document.createElement("BUTTON");
element.innerHTML = "TEXT SHOULD BE BELOW THE SQUARE";
board.appendChild(element);

var br = document.createElement("br");
board.appendChild(br);

var info = document.createTextNode("This text should also be below the SQUARE");
board.appendChild(info);

var type = " empty";

var tr = document.createElement("tr");

var td = document.createElement("td");

table.append(tr);

td.className = type;

tr.append(td);

var td2 = document.createElement("tr");

tr.append(td2);
```

```css
center {
  position: absolute;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.empty {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testclass.css">
</head>

<script src="testclass.js" defer></script>

<center>
  <div id="board">
    <table id="table">
    </table>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: center tag should be banned : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center